Check and updated language on everypage from cookie. React i18n
I am working on a website with multiple languages. I am using i18n-react. When customers logins I set up a cookie language. It will work once I reload the page, but it won't work after login immediately.
Please link if there is any way to check the language on every page from the cookie.
Thank you
i18n config
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

import ru from "./locales/ru.json"
import uz from "./locales/uz.json"

const resources = {
    ru: {
      translation: ru
    },
    uz: {
      translation: uz
    }
  }

i18n
.use(LanguageDetector) 
.use(detector)
.use(initReactI18next) 
.init({
  fallbackLng: 'ru',
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,  
  },
  detection: { 
    lookupCookie: "language",
  },
  resources: resources,
  maxRetries: 3,
});

    

export default i18n;


auth function
  const loginMutation = useLoginMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      Cookies.set("refresh", data.refresh, { expires: 7 });
      Cookies.set("access", data.access, { expires: 1 });
      Cookies.set("language", `${data?.language}`, { expires: 7 });
      navigate("/mainpage");
    },
    onFail: (error) => {
      setError(error?.response?.data?.detail);
    },
  });

I am expecting it to check and update language on everypage.

can you be more specific, please? a repository would be more than appreciating
